# c# - trying to randomize a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, shuffle

I am trying to make a 2d array that has shuffled elements in each row. For example, in a 3x5 array, each row will have 1, 2, and 3, but the order of the elements will be different:

what I want:
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
1 2 3

code I've tried:

```
       //initialize a matrix
        int[,] matrix = new int[3, 5];
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                matrix[i,j] = rnd.Next(1,3);
                Console.WriteLine(matrix[i,j]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

It seems fairly easy, but as a newbie, I've been struggling for days over this problem.
Any help or lead will be appreciated!

Comment: Should the order be different in each row or is it okay if some rows have the same order?

Comment: You never described exactly what "this problem" is.  Picking numbers randomly and individually does not assure uniqueness, so 1,2,2 is a valid result using your method.  Also,  suggested reading: [rand.next(int, int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-7.0#system-random-next(system-int32-system-int32)) where you will see that `rnd.Next(1,3)` picks a number from 1 to 2.  *Always* consult the documentation the first time you use a new class or method and *always* when you get unexpected results.

Comment: Your code seems almost right. You just need to verify, after generating each number, that it's not already on the row. This brute force approach is acceptable for rows with few elements, but may be really bad, performance wyse, for rows with many elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an List containing 1, 2, and 3, and then shuffle it for each row. Then just copy the shuffled values over:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] matrix = new int[5, 3];

    Random rnd = new Random();
    var values = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).ToList();
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        values = values.OrderBy(x => rnd.NextDouble()).ToList();
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            matrix[row, col] = values[col];
            Console.Write(matrix[row, col] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Sample Output:

```
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
1 3 2
2 1 3
Press Enter to Quit.
```

Comment: Nice solution, because it easily avoids repetitions inside each row. May be worth noting that `rnd.NextDouble()` will return a number of precision `double` in the range 0 <= n < 1. Used inside the lambda function which is passed to `OrderBy()`, this number states the position that will be assigned to each element in the new, ordered list. (A "position" doesn't need to be 0, 1 or 2; it may be 0.000, 0.231, 0.687, 0.823, etc. With the great range of a double, it will be very unlikely for two columns to have the same "position". And, even if that happens, it won't be a problem.)